# Compiler does not find wlr_backend_get_renderer when I have already included backend

Tags: c, gcc, render, window-managers, wayland

I am trying to write a Wayland compositor based on Wlroots, and I am following the description given on Drew Devault's [weblog](https://drewdevault.com/2018/02/17/Writing-a-Wayland-compositor-1.html). When I add the last changes in the page for rendering, my compilation leads to errors:

```
undefined reference to `wlr_backend_get_renderer'
undefined reference to `wlr_output_make_current'
undefined reference to `wlr_output_swap_buffers'
```

I compile my code which is exactly the one on the website, by this command:

```
gcc -o file file.c -I/usr/include/pixman-1/ -lwlroots -lwayland-server -lxkbcommon -DWLR_USE_UNSTABLE
```

Thanks for any help and sorry if it is a really stupid question.

Comment: are these functions called by file.c?

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt No, They are suppose to be in an include file in wlroots. I put the link already but it was gone after my edit. I put it back again. I guessed the code is old and wlroot updates changed the libraries. So, I am trying to use the includes similar to their tinywl example now.

Comment: don't confuse liibraries with include files. An include could only cause calls of a function if defines a macro or function that you use in file.c If the calls to `wlr_...()` come form one of the other libraries you link your program with (e.g. libwayland-server) it could be sufficient to simply change the sequence of `-l` parameters

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Thanks. I did not understand your last comment completely but, updating the includes in the beginning of the code helped as there was indeed an update in wlroots by which they have moved the functions to some other include files and the tutorial in the blog has not been updated. Therefore, I used the Tinywl includes (in the wlroots github page) and it fixed that error. I get some other errors that is not related to this topic. About the ordering of libraries like libwayland-server, does meson take care of it automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after checking some wayland compositors that update more often like Waybox and Sway, I found how to fix this problem. These functions do not exist in the newer version of wlroots and therefore one has to use their more recent replacements.
As for the rendering, [waybox](https://github.com/wizbright/waybox) uses `wlr_renderer_autocreate` instead of `wlr_backend_get_renderer`. For the other two, I just tried working with the output function in waybox which uses allocators and so I avoided the problem that way. Unfortunately, wlroots has very poor documentation and they expect you to learn by looking at the code, I guess! Therefor, I do not have detailed explanation on how I solved this problem, but, I put my code online in my [github](https://github.com/smhcpp/miniwm.git). This code is suppose to be tinywl without some capabilities with some updates for some depricated and outdated functionalities. Hope this helps people in future.